# custom dialog exception

Tags: android

ihave been used the custom dialog and an `EditText` in it , and i validate the `EditText`  by displaying error message when the user click the **ok** button without entering his/here name , but when i run it and click the ok button either with or not entering a name  an exception 
Occur why is that ? please help me..

this is my code

```
final Dialog nameDialog =new Dialog(ProfileView.this);
            nameDialog.setContentView(R.layout.namedialog);
            nameDialog.setTitle("please enter your name");
            name =(EditText)nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.nameETDialog);
            Button okButton = (Button) nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

            okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //validate the name 
                    if( name.getText().toString()== null)     
                       name.setError( " your name is requiered" );


                    else
                    { 
                      EditText nametext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_text);
                      nametext.setText(name.getText().toString());
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"your name has been entered ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                    }

    });
            Button cancelButton = (Button) nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    nameDialog.dismiss();
                }


            });

            nameDialog.show();


}
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Logcat is found in eclipse at: Window -> Show View -> Logcat

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, without Logcat, I think you have to change:

```
name =(EditText)nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.nameETDialog);
Button okButton = (Button) nameDialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
```

With

```
name =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameETDialog);
Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
```

I assume the button `okButton` is located in the layout called: `namedialog`